# D3.js - Trying to loop animations with duration time

Tags: animation, d3.js

I'm working my way on some great D3 tutorials + my on modifications to the given snippets  and I have some rather simple (I think) question.

I want to loop two functions in my code for several times. But I can't. Can you see where is my problem?

That's the code that works without looping:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="viz" style="height:80px; width:80px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var sampleSVG = d3.select("#viz")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", 300)
        .attr("height", 300);   

    sampleSVG.append("circle")
        .style("stroke", "gray")
        .style("fill", "white")
        .attr("r", 40)
        .attr("cx", 50)
        .attr("cy", 50)
        .on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "aliceblue");})
        .on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "white");})
        .on("mousedown", animateFirstStep);

    function animateFirstStep(){
         d3.select(this)
             .transition()           
            .delay(0)           
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("cx", 50)
            .attr("cy", 50)
            .attr("r", 10)
            .style("fill", "green")
            .each("end", animateSecondStep);
    };

    var newColor = function(d) {
                return 'rgb(' + Math.floor(255 * Math.random()) +
                   ', ' + Math.floor(255 * Math.random()) +
                   ', ' + Math.floor(255 * Math.random()) + ')';
                }


    function animateSecondStep(){
        d3.select(this)
          .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("r", 40)
            .style("fill", newColor)
            .each("end", animThirdStep)
        };   

    function animThirdStep() {
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("r", 25)
            .style("fill", newColor);
    }

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is how I tried to loop (the function animateFirstStep):

```
        function animateFirstStep(){
         var i=0;
        d3.select(this)
             .transition()           
            .delay(0)           
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("cx", 50)
            .attr("cy", 50)
            .attr("r", 10)
            .style("fill", "green")
            .each("end", function(i) {
                while(i < 5) {
                    animateSecondStep;
                    animThirdStep;
                    i++;
                }
            });           
    };
```

Any Suggestions? (friend suggested that it is not working because of time differences between the call to the functions and the duration of animation execution - but I don't know how to solve it)

Cheers.

Comment: In addition, How can I access d3 file without some server emulator? I want to be able to send the d3 library+my html file to a friend but it won't load without a server.

Thanks in advance

Comment: for your additional part, just change the source in your html header:     <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> now you can send it to your friend